# Javascript Push Product Info as Object to an Empty Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of products would like to add all the product information as an object to an empty array.

```
var data = {
"Vegetables": [
   {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Peas",
    "type": "Green",
},
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Carrots",
    "type": "root",
  }
],

  "Protein": [
    {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Steak",
    "type": "Meat",
},
  {
    "id": "4",
    "title": "Eggs",
    "type": "Dairy"
  }

]}
```

I am able to push just the title to the empty result array with the following:

```
function getCategory() {
result = [];
  for (let item in data) {
   data[item].forEach(v => result.push(v.title));
  }
 document.write(result);
}
getCategory();
```

But I would like to be able to push all the product information as an object so I can do some formatting.  For example:

```
    var myObj= "" ;
    myObj = "<div class='box'>" + title +"<br> "+ type + "</div>"; 
    result.push(myObj);  // push it to result[]
```

I am unsure how to adapt the body of the for loop to accommodate my object:

```
data[item].forEach(v => result.push(v.title + v.type)); // needs to be pushed as object.
```

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: `v => result.push(v))` ???

Comment: This seems like double work. If you already have the data in the `data` variable, why not just extract what you need from that instead of putting some of that data into another data structure, just to pull it out again?

Comment: maybe `v => result.push("<div class='box'>" + v.title +"<br> "+ v.type + "</div>")`

Comment: Yip that does it:)

Comment: I am not sure why I got 2 down votes because I clearly was confused, I had a specific programming problem and I gave an example of what I tried.  Very poor show.